# iOS: Matching views from large phone displays and small phone displays

Tags: ios

As a web developer for the last 10 years, I am building my first iOS app. What are the best practices for matching design from a large phone, like the iPhone 11 Pro, to a small phone like the iPhone SE? I have an app built and when running it in the Simulator, it takes the whole view and looks great on iPhone 11 Pro. When I run the app on the iPhone SE Simulator, half the view is cut off because it doesn't fit. I can resolve this by wrapping it all in a `ScrollView` so that the bottom half of the view can be seen on smaller screens but are there better practices for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all Welcome to **iOS App Development**.

And yes you are right. The layout will have some different look on different size of devices. So, that's where **Auto Layout** concept comes in. Auto Layout helps us to manage our layout according to device size and the screen design will look same on almost all devices. We can achieve Auto Layout with the help of applying **Constraints** to our controls i.e. button, label, image views etc etc. You can have a look into following link to get the idea of Auto Layout:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Very good practice is use 'center vertically' and 'center horizontally' constraints and, after that, apply 'Multiplier'parameter for each constraints. The absolute value of the multiplier will depend on the device screen size.

Comment: thanks Igor.  Isn't it virtually impossible though for content that fits on a screen in an iPhone 11 Pro to always fit on screen in a small screen like an iPhone SE?  Even using constraints, it seems like the only way I can fit the content on screen is to either 1) make it scrollable to small screens can scroll down to see the rest of the content  or 2) significantly lower the font size which will allow all the content to appear on iPhone SE's but then it looks odd on large screens

Comment: Yes it's not a silver bullet. If the interface is very complex, then it makes sense to use scroll/table/collection views. For labels you can adjust font size to control frame by using 'line brake' and 'autoshrink' properties in storyboard or sizeToFit() in code. For unbuttons adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property. You can found more examples in this site for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html). By using constraints you scale your app's views based on screen size.